# Melting columns by pattern matching

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse, melt

I have a very wide data frame that contains standard demographic characteristics (age, sex, race, education, income, and so on).  I also have respondent's answers to questions which can be prefaced in one of four ways (with "cb", "lb", "lw", or "cw").

The dataframe is currently in wide format with each row representing the answers of a single respondent.  I would like to convert this into long format, but I cannot find a straightforward solution using the reshape2 library.

I would like to preserve all the demographic characteristics as their own columns, but reduce question, answer, confidence, and score columns into their own melted columns.  Here is an idea of what I'm looking for:

```
string <- "
response_id,age,sex,race_1,race_2,race_3,cb_1,cb_1_conf,cb_1_ans,cb_1_score,lb_1,lb_1_conf,lb_1_ans,lb_1_score
11,25,M,white,NA,NA,Astrophysicist,9,Dog,0,Jackson,8,Jackson,1
22,27,F,NA,black,asian,Monkey,8,Dog,0,Jackson,7,Jackson,1"

x <- read.csv(con <- textConnection(string), header=TRUE)
```

Looks like this:

```
> x
  response_id age sex race_1 race_2 race_3           cb_1 cb_1_conf cb_1_ans cb_1_score    lb_1 lb_1_conf lb_1_ans lb_1_score
1          11  25   M  white   <NA>     NA Astrophysicist         9      Dog          0 Jackson         8  Jackson          1
2          22  27   F   <NA>  black     NA         Monkey         8      Dog          0 Jackson         7  Jackson          1
```

Looking to convert it into this form:

```
string_2 <- "
response_id,age,sex,race,question,response,confidence,correct_answer,score
11,25,M,white,cb_1,Astrophysicist,9,Dog,0
11,25,M,white,lb_1,Jackson,8,Jackson,1
22,27,F,black/asian,cb_1,Monkey,8,Dog,0
22,27,F,black/asian,lb_1,Jackson,8,Jackson,1
"

x_2 <- read.csv(con <- textConnection(string_2), header=TRUE)

  response_id age sex        race question       response confidence correct_answer score
1          11  25   M       white     cb_1 Astrophysicist          9            Dog     0
2          11  25   M       white     lb_1        Jackson          8        Jackson     1
3          22  27   F black/asian     cb_1         Monkey          8            Dog     0
4          22  27   F black/asian     lb_1        Jackson          8        Jackson     1
```

I tried subsetting the df to contain only columns that are prefixed with cb, lb, cw, or lw, followed by this:

```
    melt(subset, id=c("ResponseID"), 
    +      measure.vars=grep("^(CB|LB|LW|CW)", colnames(subset)))

But this doesn't allow me to flexibly melt the _conf columns the _ans columns and the _score columns.  

I had to modify Maurits' answer a bit to work better for my case.  Here is my solution:

df_test <- df_ans %>%
    unite(race, contains("race"), sep = "/") %>%                # combine race_1,2,3
    mutate(race = str_replace_all(race, "(/NA|NA/)", "")) %>%   # replace NA from race
    select_all( ~ gsub("(^[A-Z][A-Z]_\\d+$)", "\\1_response", .)) %>%  # add "_response" to Q
    gather(key, val, -(1:24)) %>%                                # wide to long
    separate(key, c("q1", "q2", "item")) %>%                    # split into Q + item
    unite(question, q1, q2, sep = "_") %>%                      # [continued]
    mutate(item = gsub("_", "", item)) %>%                      # [continued]
    spread(item, val) %>%                                       # long to wide
    rename(answer = ans, confidence = con)                      # rename columns
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
x %>%
    unite(race, contains("race"), sep = "/") %>%                # combine race_1,2,3
    mutate(race = str_replace_all(race, "(/NA|NA/)", "")) %>%   # replace NA from race
    select_all( ~ gsub("^(\\w+_\\d)$", "\\1_response", .)) %>%  # add "_response" to Q
    gather(key, val, -(1:4)) %>%                                # wide to long
    separate(key, c("q1", "q2", "item")) %>%                    # split into Q + item
    unite(question, q1, q2, sep = "_") %>%                      # [continued]
    mutate(item = gsub("_", "", item)) %>%                      # [continued]
    spread(item, val) %>%                                       # long to wide
    rename(answer = ans, confidence = conf)                     # rename columns
#  response_id age sex        race question  answer confidence       response
#1          11  25   M       white     cb_1     Dog          9 Astrophysicist
#2          11  25   M       white     lb_1 Jackson          8        Jackson
#3          22  27   F black/asian     cb_1     Dog          8         Monkey
#4          22  27   F black/asian     lb_1 Jackson          7        Jackson
#  score
#1     0
#2     1
#3     0
#4     1
```

Explanation:

1. Create a `unite`d `race` based on entries in `race_1,`race_2`,`race_3`, whilst removing`NA`s.
2. The rest is a matter of `gather`ing, `spread`ing and `separate`'ing entries to separate out `question`, `answer`, `confidence` and `response`.
3. I assume here that all questions have the form `\\w+_\\d` (e.g. `cb_1`, `lb_1`); adjust if necessary.

Comment: You've saved my life yet again.  Thanks SO much, Maurits.